# Prove that $\int{\exp{\{-\lambda w^2}\}} = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda} {2\pi}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, machine-learning, gaussian-integral

In machine learning, when using L2 Regularization we add a penalty of $\lambda \lVert w \rVert^2$ to our error function to get:

$ E = \sum{(y_n - \hat{y}_n)^2  } + \lambda\lVert w \rVert^2$ as our new error function.

This is equivalent to the negative log-likelihood, which we want to minimize.  In order to maximize the likelihood we multiply both sides by $-1$ and get:

$ -E = -\sum{(y_n - \hat{y}_n)^2  } - \lambda\lVert w \rVert^2$

which is equivalent to the log-likelihood.  Then, exponentiating the function, we obtain:

$\exp(-E) = [\prod\exp{\{-(y_n - w^Tx_n)^2}\}]\exp{\{-\lambda\lVert w \rVert^2}\}$.

Now I am told this yields two gaussians; the one of interest to me is the second one:

$\exp{\{-\lambda\lVert w \rVert^2}\}$.

This is a gaussian with $\mu = 0$, and $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

I can intuitively get this, since the gaussian take the form $\exp\{{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\}} $, which is then multiplied by some constant as a normalization factor.

But when I tried to convince myself, I came to the point that $\int\exp{\{-\lambda\lVert w \rVert^2}\} = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi}}$.  I can't get any farther than this.  Is there a way I can finish proving this equality to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PDF of the $N(0, \sigma^2)$ distribution, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} \int \exp\{-\frac{z^2}{2 \sigma^2}\} \, dz = 1.$$

Taking $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2 \lambda}$ yields
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp\{-\lambda z^2\} \, dz = \sqrt{\pi / \lambda}.$$

Writing $\|w\|^2 = w_1^2 + \cdots + w_d^2$, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \exp\{-\lambda \|w\|^2\} \, dw
= \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \exp\{-\lambda w_1^2\} \, dw_1 \right)^d.$$

Comment: Thank you; but I’m curious. I thought the $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda}$. Just curious why did you take $\sigma = \frac{1}{2\lambda}$?

Comment: @Hanzy $\exp(-\lambda z) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}z) \Rightarrow \lambda = \frac{1}{2\sigma^2} \Rightarrow \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2\lambda}$

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 Maybe I typed my MathJax wrong or did some step wrong because the instructor mentions that $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.  I also see that [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163388/l2-regularization-is-equivalent-to-gaussian-prior) similarly imposes a gaussian with $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda}$.  So I have messed up somewhere. Your answer makes sense from my original question, but I can't see what I've done wrong yet.

Comment: @Hanzy In the linked post, they are being loose with constants. Note that the difference in the two versions of $\lambda$ is ultimately just a factor of two in the log-likelihood.

Comment: @angryavian, ok I think I see my confusion now.  I'm trying to prove the wrong distribution.  I have a follow up question but I will put it in a new post so as not to follow up.  I understand why this answer is correct.

Comment: @angryavian I am missing the connection between the first expression and the Gaussian I am meant to be proving, which I’ve asked in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846118/456250). It seems clear the answer here is correct, I just picked the wrong expression to work with.